# No mic with Intel snd_hda_intel driver on Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, microphone, manjaro

I have a PC using Intel sound driver `snd_hda_intel`. At first, the audio did not work and so I had to go to /etc/default/grub and added `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT section, and the audio worked. When I did that, the mic did not work. I don't know if it worked before, but it doesn't now. The strange thing is the mic is not detected in pavucontrol, but is detected in evtest. `evtest` list -

```
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  HP Wireless hotkeys
/dev/input/event5:  ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer
/dev/input/event6:  ELAN072E:00 04F3:3167 Mouse
/dev/input/event7:  ELAN072E:00 04F3:3167 Touchpad
/dev/input/event8:  PC Speaker
/dev/input/event9:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event10: Video Bus
/dev/input/event11: HP WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event14: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event15: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event16: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event17: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/dev/input/event18: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
/dev/input/event19: HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru
```

So it is definitely an existing device on the system. It seems to be using the Intel driver, but it can't find the mic.
Pavucontrol mic page -

[image: pavucontrol mic page]

`lspci -v | grep -i "intel"` output (cut to relevant section) -

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci
```

Comment: This issue has been for a while, not just since the package update of Manjaro for 2021.

Comment: I also have this on a dual-boot with Windows, and the mic works there.